# why the tail of this autoexpand list can't successfully display?

Tags: c

I want to use carriage return to end up input,but why the list lost its last element. I have check my code but can't figure out why the NUll was pointed by the penult instead of the last one. The first function is to automatically establish the list, and I use `\n` as the sign to end up input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct number {
    int num;
    struct number* pnext;
} number;
number* autoexpand()
{
    char c;
    int n = 0;
    number *head = NULL, *p1, *p2;
    p1 = p2 = (number*)malloc(sizeof(number));
    scanf("%d", &p1->num);
    while (c = getchar() != '\n') {
        n++;
        if (n == 1) {
            head = p1;
        }
        else {
            p2->pnext = p1;
        }
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = (number*)malloc(sizeof(number));
        scanf("%d", &p1->num);
    }
    p2->pnext = NULL;
    return head;
}
void print(number* p)
{
    for (; p != NULL; p = p->pnext) {
        printf("%d ", p->num);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    number *p, *q;
    p = autoexpand();
    print(p);
    for (; p != NULL;) {
        q = p;
        p = p->pnext;
        free(q);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2
```

Comment: How do you use your program?

Comment: Your program won't store numbers followed by a newline character to the list.

Comment: You should use `while( scanf("%d", &p1->num) == 1)`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `getchar` at all, but if you do you should assign it to an `int` type and check for `EOF`.

Comment: Please do not add images of plain text. Insead copy the output as plain text into the question.

Comment: Hi, If my answer helped and answered the question, could you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that the use of `getchar` + `scanf` is a bit confusing to me.

I haven't tested the program but I can see the following bug in the code:

At the end of the function you are missing the last pointer `p1`, when you go out of the while loop you should save `p1` and then add `NULL` as tail.

```
p2->pnext = p1;
p1->pnext = NULL;
return head;
```

I think it should do the trick.